# How to find crash source using Android Developer Console crash report?

Tags: android, crash-reports, callstack

Since I published a new version of my app in the Google Play Store I receive crash reports in the Android Developer Console.

I have uploaded the ProGuard `mappings.txt` right after publishing the new version. Thus all log are **NOT obfuscated** (all class names and methods apear in clear text). However I am still not sure hot to read them.

**There are three major problems:**

1. The report only shows the crashing method but no line numbers. So I have no idea which part of a method caused the crash.
2. Some crash reports shows different methods using `OR`. What does this mean?
3. Not all reports are de-obfuscated. Some are still shown with anonymous class and method names

**Example:**

```
// Crash Log with is NOT obfuscated
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
1:  at com.example.MyApp.Path.To.Package.MyClass.myMethod1 (MyClass.java)  // <-- No Line Numbers...
    or                     .myMethod2 (MyClass.java)    // <-- WHAT does this OR mean???
    or                     .myMethod3 (MyClass.java)
2:  at com.example.MyApp.Path.To.Package.MyClass.onCreateView (MyClass.java)
3:  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
4:  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.access$500 (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    or                     .access$600 (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    or                     .addFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    or                     .allocBackStackIndex (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    or                     .animateRemoveFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    ...

5:  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.access$500 (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
...


// Other crash seems to show the same problem but is still obfuscated
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
1:  at com.example.MyApp.Path.To.Package.MyClass.a (MyClass.java:89)  // <-- Line numbers available here...
2:  at com.example.MyApp.Path.To.Package.MyClass.b (MyClass.java:40)
3:  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
... // Same call stack as above
```

**Questions:**

- Why are some logs de-obfuscated and other (which seem to show the same error) are not? Both logs where created after uploading the mappings file. Logs of older versions with no mappings file show an explicit "logs are obfuscated" message
- What is the meaning of the `OR` statements within the call stack? Does this mean, that the exception happened in each of these methods (how should this be possible)?
- Why are there no line numbers in the de-obfuscated logs? The given methods are quite long and without any further information I have no idea what exactly might have caused the problem. The line numbers in the obfuscated seem to point to random lines which are not linked to the real code in any way.

**So the main question is:**

**How to use the information from the logs to find the source of the crash?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following options to your Proguard configuration:

```
# This option forces Proguard to use different obfuscated names
# for different members. It avoids the 'or' stack traces.
-useuniqueclassmembernames

# These options produce useful stacktraces preserving line numbers
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Without `-useuniqueclassmembernames`, Proguard can assign identical obfuscated names for different methods from the same class (you can see it on the mapping.txt file). That's why the stacktrace knows the error happened in Method A **or** in Method B, but doesn't know exactly which one.

Using the `-useuniqueclassmembernames` option, all obfuscated names will be different and there will be no more **or** stacktraces. More information about this [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#useuniqueclassmembernames).

Apart from this, Proguard doesn't keep information about line numbers unless we use the `-renamesourcefileattribute` and `-keepattributes` options as indicated. More information about this [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#stacktrace).

These options will increase your apk size a bit, but it's totally worth it. This saved me many headaches analyzing my stacktraces.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Fabrics instead. It will give crash report along with line numbers.

Comment: While I might give it a try in a future version this is not really a solution for to the current questions, is it?